# How to set a hotkey to save and run makefile and ./a.out in vim?

Tags: vim

Proggramming c/c++ i used to :wq and make and ./a.out .

It is so annoying and inefficient ..

How to set a hotkey as :w :make :./.out in normal mode ??

Or have any tips to do it ?

Thanks :)

Comment: You seem to be asking very basic mapping questions. Really do read `:help key-mapping` and the rest of the excellent help. Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your `.vimrc` file

```
nnoremap <F5> :w <CR> :!make && ./a.out <CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a target to your Makefile that builds *and* executes the generated executable. After all, the Makefile knows best about where this is created and under which name, no need to duplicate that inside Vim.

With `:set autowrite`, the entire process then becomes a simple `:make run` (assuming the target is named `run`). This also has the benefit that any output is captured in Vim's *quickfix list*.

Of course, you can still define a mapping to speed up triggering this.

Comment: Good idea! but how to do this ? any tutorial ? :)